# Prove $\int_{|k| < 1} \frac{dk}{|k|^2} \lt \infty$ only when the dimension $d$ of $k$ is $ d \ge 3$

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $k$ be a vector of dimension $d$. Let $|k|^2 = k_1^2 + k_2^2 + ... + k_d^2$.

How can I prove that $\int_{|k| < 1} \frac{dk}{|k|^2}$ is $ \lt \infty $ only when $d \ge 3$?

Comment: Use polar coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r,\theta_1,\theta_2,\dots\theta_{d-1}$ be generalized polar coordinates. Then the integral becomes
$$
\int_{S^{d-1}}\int_0^1\frac 1{r^2}r^{d-1}dr\,d\Omega
$$
Since $d\Omega=f(\theta_1,\theta_2,\dots\theta_{d-1})d\theta_1 d\theta_2\dots d\theta_{d-1}$ where $f$ is some bounded function, convergence depends on the one-dimensional improper integral
$$
\int_0^1 r^{d-3}dr,
$$
which is convergent iff $d-3>-1$ or $d>2$ ($d\ge 3$).

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you @GReyes! Can you recommend a good reference or textbook that gives a systematic proof for high dimensional formula you wrote above? I'm not really understands how the $r^{d-1}$ terms are derived.

Comment: @PredictingTheFuture I guess this can help understand spherical coordinates and their Jacobian in any dimension https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiI57Lx483sAhVuGTQIHS0MBBsQFjARegQIFhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.avidsynergy.com%2Fpdf%2Fn_dimensional_spherical_cordinates.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2SVOb96988s2Gx1NjmOQvw